# Google Maps API - unable to set several infoWindows on several markers

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var cities = {{json|safe}};

            /*
            for (i in cities) { // 0, 1
                // document.write(cities[i]['fields']['name'] +'<br />');
                document.write(cities[i]['fields']['x'] +'<br />');
                document.write(cities[i]['fields']['y'] +'<br />');
                document.write('<br />');
            } /* */

            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.784791,-45.088806);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            var citiesLoc = new Array();
            // var flightPlanCoords = new Array();
            var infoBoxes = new Array();
            var markers = new Array();

            for (var i in cities) {
                // document.write(cities[i]['fields']['name'] );
                citiesLoc[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(cities[i]['fields']['x'],cities[i]['fields']['y']);

                // flightPlanCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(cities[i]['fields']['x'],cities[i]['fields']['y']));

                infoBoxes[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<div>" + cities[i]['fields']['name'] + "</div>"
                });

                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: citiesLoc[i],
                    map: map,
                    title: cities[i]['fields']['name']
                });


                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
                    infoBoxes[i].open(map, markers[i]);
                });


            };




            // document.write(infoBoxes[1]['content']);
            /*
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoords,
                strokeColor: "#0000ff",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 5
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
             */
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which sets up two markers with two infowindows attached, but when I click either one, only one of them (number 1 of 2, zero-indexed) shows up. If I write it like this:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(markers[0], 'click', function() {
                infoBoxes[0].open(map, markers[0]);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[1], 'click', function() {
                infoBoxes[1].open(map, markers[1]);
            });
```

then it works just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `infoBoxes[i].open(map, markers[i]);` is evaluated inside you function it will take the updated value of `i`, the one after the loop ends, i.e. `1`.

Just do an `alert(i)` in there to see that this happens.

Here's a crude fix (tested and working):

```
markers[i]._index = i;
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
    infoBoxes[this._index].open(map, markers[this._index]);
});
```

You should probably read more here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html . I know it's a lot to read, but it's sometimes necessary.

Comment: er... and how do I fix it, please?

Comment: Found some time to actually debug it. I was close with my guess. You have the clicked marker in the `this` variable.

Answer (score -1):

I really don't know what the problem is... this question is still unanswered. however this trick works: I create two more counters and use and increment them inside my loop. I really don't know why this should work, and this is not the way to program, but here goes.

```
            counter1 = 0;
            counter2 = 0;
            for (var i in cities) {
                // document.write(cities[i]['fields']['name'] );
                citiesLoc[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(cities[i]['fields']['x'],cities[i]['fields']['y']);

                // flightPlanCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(cities[i]['fields']['x'],cities[i]['fields']['y']));

                infoBoxes[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<div>" + cities[i]['fields']['name'] + "</div>"
                });

                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: citiesLoc[i],
                    map: map,
                    title: cities[i]['fields']['name']
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
                    infoBoxes[counter1++].open(map, markers[counter2++]);
                });

            };
```

Comment: wtf?! I rest in shame. my stuff is wrong of course, but I'm even more surprised that your solution does work. Can you explain this to me or point me to appropriate resources? Specifically, what is the relation between markers[i]._index and this._index, and what are the scopes of variables the way you fixed them?

Comment: Inside the click callback callback function `this` refers to the current marker (the one that was clicked), so it's the same object as `markers[i]` **at the moment the handler is added**. Note that i, being a variable, if you would address with `markers[i]`, you will get the last value assigned to `i` in each of the callbacks. So it doesn't make sense in using `i` in the click callbacks. Instead we are binding `i` to the object so we can retrieve it later from `this`. Note: The fact that the `this` object exists and it references the marker is because that is how Google implemented it.